# Java Binary to Text Algorithm?

Tags: java, string, methods, binary

What kind of algorithm/method would you use to change a simple string to binary and vice-versa (In Java)?

Comment: Pls share more about problem definition. Also provide sample input

Comment: Changing "Hello" to Binary (01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111).

Comment: A "simple String" is already binary, what else? What do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.getBytes()` returns byte array,

`String(byte[], java.lang.String)` creates new String instance from byte array an charset.

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Binary to text - Base64 encoding.
Text to binary - Base64 decoding.

Comment: Request to down voter - please enlighten me about the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BigInteger to convert it to Hex and back.

```
    byte [] binary = new byte[] {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    System.out.println("Binary: "+Arrays.toString(binary));
    String asText = new BigInteger(binary).toString(16);
    System.out.println("Text: "+asText);
    byte[] asBinary = new BigInteger(asText, 16).toByteArray();
    System.out.println("Back to Binary: "+Arrays.toString(asBinary));
```

prints:

```
Binary: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Text: 102030405
Back to Binary: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Hmmm - not a good technique - seems leading zeros are removed.